# Time complexity in big O notation of algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was given the following time complexities and was supposed to assign them to the correct "classification"(big O notation).

First off:

```
f(n) = 1000 + log_2(n^(9n))+3*n*log_1000(n^n) -> f in O(n^2*log(n))
```

Second:

```
f(n) = 2*n^3+5 * 3^n -> f in O(3^n)
```

And last but not least:

```
f(n) = 2*n^7+5*e^n -> f in O(e^n)
```

Now I'm asking for verification since I'm really not sure whether I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(n) = 1000 + log_2(n^(9n))+3nlog_1000(n^n)
```

Get rid of constants and log base

```
=> O(log(n^(n)) + nlog(n^n))
```

From log rule

```
log(a^b) = b*log(a)

=> O(nlog(n) + n*nlog(n))
=> O((n^2)*log(n))
```

---

```
f(n) = 2*n^3+5 * 3^n
```

Get rid of constants

```
=> O(n^3 + 3^n)
```

Exponential wins

```
=> O(3^n)
```

---

```
f(n) = 2n^7+5e^n
```

Get rid of constants

```
=> O(n^7 + e^n)
```

Again, exponential wins

```
=> O(e^n)
```